# Tkinter window in full width without being zoomed

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a window and because I want to hide the window bar at the top of the screen:

```
import ctypes

mainWindow = tkinter.Tk()
screen = ctypes.windll.user32
width = int(screen.GetSystemMetrics(0))
height = int(screen.GetSystemMetrics(1))-40 
mainWindow.geometry(str(width)+'x'+str(height)+'-0-32') # <----------- signaled line
```

The problem is that I'm not being abble to get a full width window.

In the signaled line if I write (-0):

```
mainWindow.geometry(str(width)+'x'+str(height)+'-0
```

... I get a lack to cover in the right side of the screen.

In the signaled line if I write (+0):

```
mainWindow.geometry(str(width)+'x'+str(height)+'+0
```

I get a lack to cover in the left side of the screen.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using the standard winfo_screenwidth() commands?

Comment: Why didn't you just call `mainWindow.attributes("-fullscreen", 1)`?

Answer (score 0):

To hide the window bar (regardless of size) you can call root.overrideredirect(True).
I frequently use this code to fullscreen:

```
root.overrideredirect(True)
root.geometry('{0}x{1}+0+0'.format(root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()))
```

you can obviously modify this to format it to just the screenwidth and a constant pixel size height (though I'm unsure of why you'd want to do that)